# Rails - Puma - Nginx : How to redirect all to https://www.example.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I have a Rails app, everything works well.

My nginx configure file :

```
upstream puma-enziin {
  server unix:///home/kevin/websites/enziin/shared/tmp/sockets/enziin-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name enziin.com;

  root /home/kevin/websites/enziin/current/public;

  access_log /home/kevin/websites/enziin/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/kevin/websites/enziin/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma-enziin;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/enziin.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/enziin.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

My question: How to redirect all to https ://www.example.com ?

With above configure, it can redirect to https ://example.com, not to https ://www.example.com

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
server_name enziin.com;
```

to this:

```
server_name enziin.com www.example.com;
```

The above makes nginx to serve to two hosts. Currently it is only mapping itself for `enzinn.com`. After this, your existing configuration should also work for `www.example.com`, and will start redirecting to its `https` equivalent.

(Make sure www.example.com's DNS record points to your nginx)